# Mysql найти записи которые имеют одинаковое значение поля до определенного символа

Tags: mysql, sql

Как с помощью mysql найти записи которые имеют одинаковое значение поля до определенного символа?

Пример:

```
[id]     [value]
0        11#1
1        12#44
2        11#12
```

Вывод:

```
[id]     [value]
0        11#1
2        11#12
```

Символ конечно будет другой, как и другая структура таблицы.

Comment: А `LIKE '11%'` Вам не подходит почему?

Comment: Like конечнобы подошел. но я не знаю что за текст до символа #. Мне надо найти одинаковые записи.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

не совсем понятно что вы имеете ввиду.
Какой должен быть результат, например, на таких данных:

```
id  value   
0   111#12313   
1   22#fdsasd   
2   22#qweert   
3   33333#qwertrewq 
4   111#werwr   
5   22#qqqq
6   qweqweqw
```

Вот запрос, который подсчитывает для каждой строки количество повторений подстроки до символа #:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '#')-1) as pref, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM tablename
  WHERE INSTR(value, '#') > 0
  GROUP BY SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '#')-1)
  /*HAVING COUNT(*) > 1*/
)T1 
  JOIN tablename T2 ON value LIKE CONCAT(pref, '#%')
```

На приведённых выше данных запрос выдаст:

```
id  value           pref    cnt
0   111#12313       111     2
1   22#fdsasd       22      3
2   22#qweert       22      3
3   33333#qwertrewq 33333   1
4   111#werwr       111     2
5   22#qqqq         22      3
```

Если раскоментировать `/*HAVING COUNT(*) > 1*/`- то запрос выведет только те строки, префикс у которых неуникальный(повторяется как минимуму один раз).

**UPD:** условие соединения заменил на `value LIKE CONCAT(pref, '#%')`, чтобы при наличии индекса по value - он использовался.

При желании можно вообще обойтись без двух чтений из таблицы talename. В MySQL нет функции `COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY)`, однако это можно организовать с помощью переменных в запросе. В два этапа: сначала пронумеровать строки в каждой группе, потом найти максимум номера в группе.

Comment: Да-да, вы правильно понели "Вот запрос, который подсчитывает для каждой строки количество повторений подстроки до символа #:"

Comment: Вроде работает, но что-то странно записи 3 точно удовлетворяют условию, а выдало 9 такихже записей. Причем их в базе данных нету какбы клоны.

Comment: HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 не помог.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, там опечатка была в условии соединения таблиц. Поправил ответ. Посмотрите сейчас.

Comment: Да, теперь вижу работает, спасибо